# Not able to display blob as image in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, blob

I'm trying to display an image stored as blob in flutter. I'm using a PHP API to get the image and send it as a base64 string. When the image builds, there is an error that says  `Failed decoding image. Data is either invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.`
Running an xampp server. PHP APIs. Flutter application run using android studio emulator

I am able to display the image on a webpage using a HTML img tag.

```
Image.memory(base64Decode(imagebase64string));
```

I expect the image to be shown on the screen
Error says

```
Failed decoding image. Data is either invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.
```

Comment: Please add your code with the encoded base64 string.

Comment: var url = 'http://192.168.0.104:80/bah/api/get_image.php';
var response = await http.get(url);
image_string = base64Decode(response.body.toString());

Comment: //in the widget in a row I have "Image.memory(image_string)"

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove base64 header manualy:

```
    final stripped =
        imagebase64string.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'data:image/[^;]+;base64,'), '');
    setState((){
      data = base64.decode(stripped);
    });
```

Then you can use `data` with `Image.memory`.

```
Image.memory(data)
```

Comment: Still says the same thing

Comment: This is my image base64 string

Comment: 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

Comment: Only half of it though

Comment: No more thoughts, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Decode it back to a byte array from base64 and use this from `dart.ui`:

```
final codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data);
final frame = await codec.getNextFrame();
return frame.image;
```

Or even simpler, from `package:flutter/widgets.dart`:

```
return decodeImageFromList(data);
```